# Property 'loadItems' does not exist on type '{ methods: { loadItems: ActionMethod; }; mounted(): void; }'

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3, vuex-modules, vuex4

I use modulare vuex store, for each module of app has own store, I want to execute an action of my vuex store, the state, mutaion and action are created, but when I execute the action in the view I have error:
Property 'loadItems' does not exist on type '{ methods: { loadItems: ActionMethod; }; mounted(): void; }

Index.vue:

```html
<template>
    <h1> table page </h1>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts">
// import store from "@/modules/table/store";

import { mapActions } from 'vuex';



export default {

    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'loadItems'
        ])
    },

    mounted (){
     this.loadItems();
    }
}

</script>
```

store/index.ts:

```js
    import { createStore } from 'vuex'
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default createStore({
      
        state: {
            items: [],
        },
    
        mutations: {
            SET_Item (state, items) {
                state.items = items
            }
        },
    
        actions: {
            loadItems ({ commit }) {
                axios
                .get('http://127.0.0.0/api/vendor/index/', {
                    headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                      Authorization: "Bearer " + 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJpc3NhbSIsImlhdCI6MTYzMjEyNjQ2'
                    },
                  })
                    .then(response => response.data)
                    .then(items => {
                     console.log('items is:',items);
                    commit('SET_Items', items)
                })
            }
        },
    });
```

shims-vuex.d.ts:

```js
    /* eslint-disable */
    declare module '*.vue' {
      import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
      const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
      export default component
    }
```